# Result of toJSON() on a date is different between IE8 and IE9+

Tags: javascript, json, datetime, internet-explorer-8

I'm doing a conversion from Date to string and back for using in sessionStorage.
so I first do this:

```
sessionStorage.currentDate = myDate.toJSON();
```

and then I do this:

```
if (sessionStorage.currentDate ) {
    myDate = new Date(sessionStorage.currentDate);
}
```

The problem is that the `myDate.toJSON()` function in **IE9+** returns `"2013-05-06T22:00:00.000Z"` but in IE8 it returns `"2013-05-06T22:00:00Z"` missing the decimal part at the end.

The fact is that in IE8 is failing the subsequent re-conversion into a date (the result from `new Date(sessionStorage.currentDate)` is `NaN`)

Any idea why this is happening and how to make this code work for IE8+?

#### Update:

I tried to replace the string in debug, and it turns out that none of the 2 strings works. So it actually seems to be a problem of the `new Date(sessionStorage.currentDate)` not recognizing the format (which is UTC)

Comment: Are you sure that the IE9 example is correct? That's three digits allowed for the number of seconds. Did you mean 22:00:00.000Z?

Comment: sorry I corrected the question

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Prior to ES5, parsing of dates was entirely implementation dependent. IE 8 (and lower) won't parse the ISO 8601 format specified in ES5, so just parse it yourself:

```
// parse ISO format date like 2013-05-06T22:00:00.000Z
function dateFromISO(s) {
  s = s.split(/\D/);
  return new Date(Date.UTC(s[0], --s[1]||'', s[2]||'', s[3]||'', s[4]||'', s[5]||'', s[6]||''))
}
```

Assumes the string is UTC.

Comment: This is actually what Iøm already doing for dates coming from wcf web services, so I already have the function. wasn't expectiong to need it for dates I converted myself. I'm gonna try if my function works and then I'll accept this answer.

Comment: I would recommend storing just the time value, then you just do `new Date(timeValue)`. There's no point in creating a formatted string that will need to be parsed to be useful anyway.

Answer (score 2):

I don't believe the different number of places is a case of something 'not working'. From https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Times:

> Decimal fractions may also be added to any of the three time elements. [...] A fraction may only be added to the lowest order time element in the representation. To denote "14 hours, 30 and one half minutes", do not include a seconds figure. Represent it as "14:30,5", "1430,5", "14:30.5", or "1430.5". **There is no limit on the number of decimal places for the decimal fraction.** However, the number of decimal places needs to be agreed to by the communicating parties.

Therefore, as toJSON converts a time to ISO-8601 format, and both strings you mention are valid ISO-8601, it appears that both are correct - they just happen to be *different*.

In terms of a fix, a simple regex replace should do the trick - replace all matches for `\.\d+Z` with just `Z` (I'm assuming you don't need millisecond-level accuracy!). This should give you a string that works on IE8 even if it was generated from IE9

Comment: I know it's allowed but the conversion just return NaN in ie8 and I canøt explain why. I don't see the proposed solution fro m zerkms

Comment: The time with the .000 is a perfectly valid representation, but just not one that IE8 understands, hence you getting NaN. The proposed solution I originally mentioned has unfortunately been deleted, so I've added one of my own instead.

Comment: I added an update after trying your solution. I think the problem is different thatn what I thought initially

Comment: It is, yes - take a read of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5802461/javascript-which-browsers-support-parsing-of-iso-8601-date-string-with-date-par for solutions to the new problem.

Comment: @MaurizioIndenmark Do you need to store the dates as JSON format? Ticks or similar are more portable between platforms, and avoid workarounds.

Comment: No I need to save the dates into a sessionStorage that is only string, and then re-casting it into a string

Comment: Your ticks could be strings too. Or, store your date in yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss format. Basically, you're using a date format that is only supported in a subset of browsers; I'm just suggesting you consider using a format with wider support, and avoiding hacky workarounds.

Comment: I thought the toJson was the best way. bu I don't care how I will save the date, as long as I can recover it later on. all in UTC

Answer (score -2):

I think you need to IE8 specific browser hack for this. And for this need to extra code like...

```
if(jQuery.browser.msie && jQuery.browser.version.substring(0, 1) == 8) {
    // add extra missing zero
}
```

Comment: May be, it is better to use a "feature detection?
Something like so 
if (new Date("2013-12-31T00:00:00.000Z") === NaN) {
window.paseDateEx = function(str) { /* manual parsing*/ };
} else {
window.parseDateEx = function (str) { return new Date(str); }
}