# Date object returns NaN when trying to calculate time between two dates in IE8

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, datetime, internet-explorer-8

I have a **string** which represents the expiry of an item like so: `2020-10-31T21:30:11`, and I have a function to calculate the amount of days left until this date (below).

However, in IE8 it doesn't work. I think this is because `timeEnd` is returning `NaN`. Can someone **explain why this doesn't work** and point me in the right direction?

I have a [jsFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/q3AyS/1).

And here's a snippet of my code:

**HTML**

```
<span class="days-left" data-publishend="2020-10-31T21:30:11"></span>
```

**JS**

```
$('.days-left').each(function () {

    if ($(this).data("publishend")) {
        var timeEnd = new Date($(this).data("publishend")), // returns NaN in IE8
            timeNow = new Date(),
            oneDay = 24*60*60*1000,
            oneHour = 60*60*1000,
            oneMin = 60*1000,
            daysLeft = Math.floor(Math.abs(timeEnd.getTime() - timeNow.getTime())  / oneDay),
            hoursLeft = Math.floor(Math.abs(timeEnd.getTime() - timeNow.getTime())  / oneHour),
            minsLeft = Math.floor(Math.abs(timeEnd.getTime() - timeNow.getTime())  / oneMin),
            string;

        if (daysLeft < 1) {
            if (hoursLeft < 1.5) {
                string = minsLeft + ' minutes';
            } else {
                string = hoursLeft + ' hours left';
            }
        }
        if (daysLeft === 1) string = '1 day left';
        if (daysLeft > 1) string = daysLeft + ' days left';

        $(this).text(string);
    }
});
```

Comment: IE8 doesn't know how to parse that date string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From looking at answers in [this Stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2182246/javascript-dates-in-ie-nan-firefox-chrome-ok), I've got a grasp of what was going on and created my own function that worked the string that I wanted to convert a date object.

IE8 cannot parse the string `2020-10-31T21:30:11` like other browsers can. But the date object can accept comma separated values representing the year, month, day, etc, and use them to create the new instance ([more info about the Date object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date)).

So I created a function that takes my string, spits it at the "T" and then splits the remaining values at either the "-" or the ":". The function then returns the a date object instance using these values as the parameters.

```
function parseDateString(dateString) {
    var a = dateString.split('T'),
        year = a[0].split('-')[0],
        month = a[0].split('-')[1],
        day = a[0].split('-')[2],
        hour = a[1].split(':')[0],
        min = a[1].split(':')[1];

    return new Date(year, month - 1, day, hour, min);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are right, IE8 won't parse your date right at the beginning (timeEnd init).
Here is the reason : https://stackoverflow.com/a/17593482/2143734
Just one more date handling issue ;)

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
function parseISO8601(dateStringInRange) {
    var isoExp = /^\s*(\d{4})-(\d\d)-(\d\d)\s*$/,
        date = new Date(NaN), month,
        parts = isoExp.exec(dateStringInRange);

    if(parts) {
      month = +parts[2];
      date.setFullYear(parts[1], month - 1, parts[3]);
      if(month != date.getMonth() + 1) {
        date.setTime(NaN);
      }
    }
    return date;
  }
```

to make the conversion.

Source: [Date constructor returns NaN in IE, but works in Firefox and Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2182246/javascript-dates-in-ie-nan-firefox-chrome-ok)